# how to get data from master table using outer join for muliple columns

Tags: sql-server, outer-join

I have two tables

```
employees (id, employee_name, hire_date ...)
```

The second table data links manager with 3 employees (at most), or two employees or one.

```
Emp_Managed (mgr_id, emp1, emp2, emp3,
 mgr_id references employees id,
 emp1 references employees id,
 emp2 references employees id,
 emp3 references employees id,
)
```

I want to select all data from emp_managed not to show IDs, but names and hire dates.

I want to get name and hire for manager and for all employees managed by this manager which are emp1, emp2, emp3 by using join or another way (but not using select in select clause)

how can I do so?

Comment: Do you have any sample data? Have you tried anything? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Bad data design

Comment: Please read [ask] & other [help] links, show some work. Also [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start with something like the query below.  The key is to use table aliases so you can JOIN with the same table multiple times.

```
SELECT mgr.id AS manager_id,
    mgr.employee_name AS manager_name,
    mgr.hire_date AS manager_hire_date,
    e1.id AS emp1_id,
    e1.employee_name AS emp1_name,
    e1.hire_date AS emp1_hire_date,
    e2.id AS emp2_id,
    e2.employee_name AS emp2_name,
    e2.hire_date AS emp2_hire_date,
    e3.id AS emp3_id,
    e3.employee_name AS emp3_name,
    e3.hire_date AS emp3_hire_date
FROM Employees mgr
INNER JOIN Emp_Managed em
    ON  em.mgr_id = mgr.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN Employees e1
    ON  e1.id = em.emp1
LEFT OUTER JOIN Employees e2
    ON  e2.id = em.emp2
LEFT OUTER JOIN Employees e3
    ON  e3.id = em.emp3
WHERE mgr.id = 1
```

I've chosen to use LEFT OUTER JOINs for the employees in case you allow those fields to be null.

Your schema in `Emp_Managed` is denormalized because you've got repeating groups, so this is about the best you can do easily.  Usually this sort of thing is represented with a hierarchical structure that requires a recursive query, but it doesn't appear like your structure is like that.  If you do have a situation where you want the manager, all employees he or she manages, and then all employees managed by those employees, it gets significantly more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like that;

```
select E.employee_name,E2.employee_name,E3.employee_name,E4.employee_name from Emp_Managed EM 
inner join employees E ON EM.mgr_id = E.id
inner join employees E2 ON EM.emp1 = E2.id
inner join employees E3 ON EM.emp2 = E3.id
inner join employees E4 ON EM.emp3 = E4.id
```